# objective-c disable drag in UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, draggable

I want to disable UIButton dragging in Xcode, is there anyway to do that?

any solution would help

Thanks

Comment: do you mean dragging like in drag and drop?

Comment: yes but I want to disable the dragging, once I've touch from from UIbutton and slide it performs the dragging action. So I just wonder can I disable the dragging action

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable touch drag events, but can use alternative of handling them.
You need to handle Touch event handlers. When we swipe left or right TouchCancel event is fired and when you swipe up or down TouchDragExit is fired. Make sure to implement both.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL buttonFullyTouched;
.
.
.
//Touch Down Event

```
- (IBAction)filterTouchedDown:(id)sender
{    
    _nameButton.selected = NO;
    _codeButton.selected = NO;
    _dateButton.selected = NO;

    _filterFullyTouched = NO;
}
```

//Touch Drag Exit Event

```
- (IBAction)buttonDragExit:(id)sender
{
    if (!_buttonFullyTouched)
    {
        UIButton *randomButton = (UIButton *)[_groupView viewWithTag:_previousButtonSelectedTag + 2000];
        randomButton.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

// Touch Cancel Event

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchCancel:(id)sender
{
    if (!_buttonFullyTouched)
    {
        UIButton *randomButton = (UIButton *)[_groupView viewWithTag:_previousButtonSelectedTag + 2000];
        randomButton.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

// TouchUpInside event

```
- (IBAction)groupButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    _nameButton.selected = NO;
    _codeButton.selected = NO;
    _dateButton.selected = NO;

    _buttonFullyTouched = YES;

    // logic for further code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to disallow the user to drag-out from a touch, look at the UIControl class. Specifically take note of:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

If you're using InterfaceBuilder, you should look at the options available for Events (in the Inspector window, second tab).

Comment: Yes I have been studying the UIControl class and the button connection in IB, but what I want to ask is HOW to disable the drag-out function of that button. The situation now is that I have 2 UIbuttons on the screen, if the user click one button first and slide over the second one, it will trigger the drag out action for the first button but what I want to do is to trigger "touch down" action of the second button.

Comment: I'm not certain I completely understand your question, but I'll try to answer. You should be able to set a target:action: for the drag out event on button one, where the target is 'button 2' and the action is 'touch down'.